# How to get full screen programs to recognize my actual screen size?

Tags: windows-8, gaming, resizing

I recently bought a razor blade 14. The computer is fine but for some reason full screen programs always over estimate the size so when ever a get a new game from steam the application always starts up zoomed in. Please can some one tell me how to fix this, is it a program I need, or do I have to change some thing. The computers OS is windows 8.1 and is up to date.

Comment: Could you please make an example screenshot? Also, what’s the [Windows scaling setting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/r7wtB.png) set to?

Answer (score 0):

This is a general problem with PC gaming. Usually you have to input the right screen resolution when you first load a game. Also, the Razor Blade has a very non-standard 3200 x 1800 screen, which probably makes it less likely it will be detected.

Comment: Yea I know but is there a way of fixing this

Comment: Nvidia have an app called Geforce Experience and AMD have another called Gaming Evolved that set video settings automatically, but I'm not sure if they deal with screen resolutions.